# 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel web application that works perfectly on my server but when I try to install it locally on wamp, I keep getting this error

> The requested URL /rms/public/users/dashboard was not found on this
>   server.

I have mod_rewrite enabled.
I can't seem to find a .htaccess in /public/ folder.

Comment: Can't you download the .htaccess from your server?

Comment: Probably the missing .htaccess is the problem. Getting it from your server or laravel source will solve the problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but I highly suggest you ditch Wamp and look into [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com). I doubt you'd regret it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the .htaccess file and put it into your public folder.

[Here' the link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)

And it's better to follow the [installation guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation) to create a laravel project locally, and replace your app and public folder with the ones on server

Answer (score 0):

Have you try checking composer.. sometimes you maybe using packages that are under the gitignore folder so the wont come across... if you do a pull...